# GetChild from GameObject Array (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a trouble of getting the child from an array of GameObject

Here's my script:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject[] CameraScriptsTV;

protected override void SetPosition()
{
CameraScriptsTV = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject; //here is the error
   foreach (GameObject TV_CameraScript in CameraScriptsTV)
      {
         TV_CameraScript.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
      }
}
```

I'm getting the child using what has been written on [Transform.GetChild.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)

What I am trying to do is like this for example:

In this script I get the child from the Camera in my hierarchy : 
[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPUJO.jpg)

```
CameraScriptsAir_1 = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject;
CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
CameraScriptsAir_1.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
```

So what i am getting here is the AIR_1(Clone) then get the script `Bloom.cs` and `DepthOfFieldDeprecated.cs`.

I hope its clear.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `GetChild(0)` returns a single `Transform`. Getting that single Transfrom's `GameObject` can never, and will never, result in an array of anything.

Comment: @Draco18s actually that was just an example of how i'm getting a child sir.

Comment: @Steve could not convert `GameObject to GameObject[]` something like that

Comment: @NoobProgrammer then you're hitting the problem Draco18s is describing. Try creating a list and adding the gameobject to it.

Comment: @Steve i've edited my question

Comment: Your question/problem is still not clear. [`Transform.GetChild()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) still only returns ***one*** Transform, the docs make that quite clear. "Returns: `Transform` child by index."  Not `Transform[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by doing it like this

```
CameraScriptsTV[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(5).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
CameraScriptsTV[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(6).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
CameraScriptsTV[2] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(7).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

instead of doing it as a foreach statement . But still i'm not satisfied because this is a bad practice . I don't know also how to shorten or optimize this code as a for loop statement.

EDIT: So from there i came up with this

```
for(int i=0; i<29; i++)
{
    Tests[i]= this. transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(i+7).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject; 
}
```

Comment: thats not very generic either, a lot of magical numbers. i also doubt its less work than assigning the references in the inspector. just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do is this

```
protected override void SetPosition()
 { 
 foreach (Transform TV_CameraScript in this.transform)
 { 
         TV_CameraScript.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
 } 
}
```

I don't understand why you would want an array of **gameobjects** just to modify a component.

Comment: To which object is the current script attached ?

Comment: Then why the extra getChilds()?

Comment: I uses it instead of GameObject.Find cause its way more faster. And i put it on an array because they're both the same path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's another shortcut for you to achieve this, you can get all the Bloom component with GetComponentsInChildren();

Here's the solution.

```
[SerializeField]
Bloom[] bloomComponents;

protected override void SetPosition()
{
    //Get all Bloom components from child, and store it in global variable
    bloomComponents = this.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Bloom>();

    //Loop to it and disable it
    foreach (Bloom bloom in bloomComponents)
    {
        bloom.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

## EDIT 1

If your transform has more than one branch, we need to find it recursively, which we will do with some helper method.!

Don't forget to include `using System.Collections.Generic` in top of your script, because we use List<> Class

```
[SerializeField]
Bloom[] bloomComponents;

protected override void SetPosition()
{
    //Only do it once, we don't want to make it expensive
    if (bloomComponents.Length == 0)
    {
        //Get all Bloom components from child, and store it in global variable
        bloomComponents = GetComponentsInChildrenRecursively<Bloom>(this.transform);
    }

    //Loop to it and disable it
    foreach (Bloom bloom in bloomComponents)
    {
        bloom.enabled = false;
    }
}

//Autoatically Find Component Recursively
public T[] GetComponentsInChildrenRecursively <T>(Transform root)
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    if (root.childCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform t in root)
        {
            //this root has transform in it, so recursive
            //it will call GetComponentsInChildrenRecursively over and over again, till no child
            results.AddRange(GetComponentsInChildrenRecursively<T>(t));
        }
    }

    //Add to the results
    results.AddRange(root.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<T>());
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

if this show some error, please tell me, as my office laptop don't have unity IDE, i can't test it.

*Please Note : don't use this in very huge Transform Hierarchy, since it will loop through all of it.*

Comment: How can it find the bloom script sir from all of those components ? Could you explain sir

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Bloom>();` will find all script type of Bloom inside the gameObject, so you don't have to trace around the `transform.GetChild()`, it will automatically do the job, see reference https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html

Comment: So i don't have to drag anything on the inspector . Cause what my code doing is I'm not dragging them anymore they're automatically been place on the components.

Comment: It do the same as your codes, the only difference is it way more simpler and readable. it will drag (or u should call it, 'Apply') all bloom components to the inspector.

Comment: it's up to you whether you want to use this way or another way, because in programming there is a lot of way in doing a same thing ;)

Comment: Let me try this thing if this work sir i will mark this answer. Thank you

Comment: It didn't do anything sir still this script works for me in a way that i don't like it because its not optimize. `Tests[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(9).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;` then disable it like this `foreach(GameObject test in Tests){ test.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false }`

Comment: hmm, so let me guess, your Bloom script is in child of a child of a child gameObject, isn't it?, if it correct then you have to find it recursively, let me see..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163176/discussion-between-endrik-exe-and-noobprogrammer).

Comment: the problem with this is that i have a huge transform so this won't do . I only want to get all the camera from [here](https://imgur.com/a/jNnHx) . So your code basically do all the transform as long as there's a child right sir? But what i am doing is basically getting a transform in only 1 gameobject with some childs in it